# Java: Strange issue with java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I thought I understood the concept of generics, until today I found this problem:
I am using Java 11. I know, that the design of the following code does not really make sense, it is only intended to reproduce the problem that I found in my actual project.

Imagine, I have the following classes:

```
public class Pet {}

public class Cat extends Pet {
  private String catName;
  // ... Constructor, Getter, Setter;
}

public class Dog extends Pet {
  private String dogName;
// ... Constructor, Getter, Setter;
}

public interface PetExchanger<IN_TYPE extends Pet, OUT_TYPE extends Pet> {
  OUT_TYPE exchange(IN_TYPE pet);
}

public class PetExchangings<S extends Pet> {

  public <IN_TYPE extends Pet, OUT_TYPE extends Pet> void exchangingRule(Class<IN_TYPE> inClass Class<OUT_TYPE> outClass,
      PetExchanger<IN_TYPE, OUT_TYPE> f) {
    // no matter what happens here ...
  }
}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PetExchangings().exchangingRule(Dog.class, Cat.class, d -> new Cat(d.getDogName()));
  }
}
```

This code does NOT compile, unless I remove the generics definition `<S extends Pet>` on the class `PetExchangings`. If I remove it, everything is fine, but with this definition added (which does not seem to influence anything!) suddenly the call of `exchangingRule(...)` from the `main` method does not compile any more: The type of the argument "`d`" in the lambda expression is suddenly not evalutated as `Dog` any more but is only a `Pet`. And thus the method `d.getDogName()` can not be found.

Can someone please explain to me, why does this happen? How does the generics argument added to the `PetExchangings` class influence this behavior? It seems to be in no way bound to the executed method.

Comment: You are using raw types, aren't you? Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) before?

Comment: Why close this question? I was just posting an answer: if you want to use `PetExchangings<S extends Pet>` you should add a type on initialization: `new PetExchangings<Cat>()`. But in this context, it does not make sense to add the generic type to the `PetExchangings` because it is never used.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I was not aware of this behavior of raw types ...